# Understanding the p-value

Tags: self-study, p-value

I'm studying the second course in statistics, and now I have a problem to understand $P$-values. Namely, one exercise is the following.

When testing hypothesis $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$ one gets the value of test statistic $z=1.7$. Determine the $P$-value for the alternative hypothesis $H_A:\mu>\mu_0$.

Is it that I have to calculate the $P$-value from $N(0,1)$-distribution or is there some other distribution in the background?

Comment: This sounds like homework so I will add the homework tag. You can delete it if I am mistaken.

Comment: @PeterFlom It is indeed a homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track; think about what the z-statistic means. I am not sure what you mean by "count the p-value" but that may be just a linguistic problem.

Comment: So my problem is that in my lecture notes the example are from normal distribution. But as that is not said explicitly in the problem, should I assume that we test the hypothesis from $N(0,1)$-distribution? Probably I should try to find some lecture notes where P-values are defined more rigorously.

Comment: If the statistic is a z-value you can assume their discussion a normal distribution.  Z-values are derived from the standard normal distribution.

Comment: @JaakkoSeppälä Does the first sentence of the [wikipedia article on p-values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) (which correctly defines the term) help you?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes it helps. John's comment was helpful as now I  know that the values are derived from the standard normal distribution.